# why do i get a unreported exception FailedToRunRaspistillException?

Tags: java, netbeans, camera, raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 and a camera module. I am trying to take a picture using Java in NetBeans. I had to get a jrpicam-1.0.1.jar file for the Raspberry Pi lib. I got it from here, https://github.com/Hopding/JRPiCam.

I am just trying to run this basic code but i get the error.

```
public class camera{
   RPiCamera piCamera = new RPiCamera();
   piCamera.takeStill("picture.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Check out [ask] for tips on how to get the most out of this site.  In this case, however, you are declaring a class and then coding as if you have a method there.  You probably need to get information on how to do some basic Java programming, as you need to have at minimum a `main` method for your program to start doing anything.

Comment: Show complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/Hopding/JRPiCam/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hopding/jrpicam/RPiCamera.java#L80

You need the `raspistill` program installed so your program can call it.

Comment: You will need to learn how to investigate a stack trace and see in the source what caused the problem.  This will allow you to figure things out like this on your own :)

Comment: I get the same issue and I have raspistill installed. In fact I used the example code from git.